# How do I get a reference to a component on a sibling object in C# Script?

Tags: unity, c#, hierarchy

I'm working on a game, where the player dumps trash from Trash cans into a Trash Truck. These Trash cans have a random chance of having a Racoon on top of them.

I have a script set up to detect when the player enters a Collider Trigger attached to the Racoon, which will cause it to play an animation and start attacking the player.

To do that, it needs to work with a racoon navigation component on a neighbouring object:

[image: Unity Script Hierarchy]

I'm trying to access the `RacoonNAVAI` component on the `Racoon_Mover` game object with this line:

```
racNav = transform.parent.parent.Find("Racoon Mover").gameObject.GetComponent<RacoonNAVAI>();
```

But it's throwing a null reference exception. How can I correctly get a reference to this component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line below you are looking for `Racoon Mover` instead of `Racoon_Mover`, note the `_` (underscore symbol).

```
racNav = transform.parent.parent.Find("Racoon Mover").gameObject.GetComponent<RacoonNAVAI>();
```

Also, it is not a good idea to use find in runtime code like this. Instead, you can assign it as a serialized component if they are part of the same prefab or at least cache the reference so that you won't need to look it up each time. Good luck!

Comment: Wow, that fixed it, thanks.
And, so, I have more than one of these Trash cans, and they can be parented to the Trash Truck. And I want these Trash cans to be independent of one another, I want all the related scripts to be self-contained within each Trash can. So Setting it to ```[SerializeField]``` would do that? And how would I cache the reference? Thanks.

Comment: You may also want to consider `transform.parent.parent.GetComponentInChildren<RacoonNAVAI>()` - shorter, no string comparisons or corresponding breakages if you misspell/change a name, and it gets you the component directly without a second search.

Comment: @DMGregory Ok, thanks. It's funny, I thought there was a better way of doing this than having to put in .parent a billion / multiple times. I guess not, interesting. Thanks.

Comment: The better way is the serialized variable.

Comment: Oh, ok, thanks.